# Codeigniter 4 - how to auto load custom config file?

Tags: php, codeigniter

New to CI4, been using CI3 for a while. Now I'm trying to move from CI3 to CI4 but I'm struggling a lot, documentation is not as complete as the one for CI3 so thank you if you can help me

What I would like to do is store in a configuration file some values and retrieve those values inside a view.

for instance I have in app/config/CustomConfig.php file

```
<?php namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class CustomConfig extends BaseConfig
{
    public $session_timeout  = 300;

    public $languages = array(
      "1" => "italian",
      "2" => "english"
    );
    public $languages_label = array(
      "1" => "Italiano",
      "2" => "English"
    );
}
```

than I have a controller that extends BaseController and echoes the login.php view

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Login extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $output=array();

    if(isset($this->session->logged_user)){
        redirect('Main', 'refresh');
    }

    $this->_print_output('login.php',$output);
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

in BaseController.php I've added the following inside the initController function

```
public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // E.g.:
        $session = \Config\Services::session();
        $my_config = config('CustomConfig');

    }
```

in CI3 in my view I would have use

```
              foreach ($this->config->item('languages_label') as $key => $value) {
                  echo('<a class="dropdown-item" href="?hl='.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>');
              }
```

so I'm looking for something similar to

```
foreach ($my_config->languages_label as $key => $value) {
                  echo('<a class="dropdown-item" href="?hl='.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>');
              }
```

but I've got a:
**Undefined variable: my_config **

Tried also
$this->my_config = config('CustomConfig');
in BaseController and in the view but with no luck

if I put directly in the view
$my_config = config('CustomConfig');
it works but I would like to use $my_config in other pages so loading only once would be ideal (like the old $autoload['config'] = array('custom_config'); )

any hints is appreciated
thanks!

Comment: Are you able to access `$this->my_config` in `Login` or `Base` controller itself?

Comment: no, same "undefined variable" there too..